# How to store javascript code without it executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have adsense javascript code added to a designated div location using jquery but it seems javascript code does not sit well inside a jquery variable. It executes. I've tried using php's htmlentities to encode it for storage, but I can't get it to decode naturally. What should I do? Do I need a javascript based replacement for htmlentities_decode?

This is how far I've gotten, and .html() is not automatically decoding the htmlentities encoded html.

```
var html_1 = "<?php echo htmlentities('<script>adsense ad code here</script>'); ?>";
if (html_1)
{
    jQuery('#id_wpt_adblock_1').html(html_1);
}
```

Comment: He is just trying to bypass adblock showing his adsense. That isn't nice thing to do.

Comment: Presuming the negative vocally isn't a nice thing to do.  I'm doing maintenance work on my ad placement plugin WPTrafficTools. I didn't know until now that it had trouble placing adsense code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`<script>` tags are automatically executed when they are added to the DOM.  So, when the string is added via `html()`, the `<script>` is added to the DOM, and than ran.</strike>

The issue here, is the `<script>` tags in the string.  When the browser sees 'em, it may try to run the script.  Try to change the string to this:

```
var html_1 = "<?php echo '<scr"+"ipt>adsense ad code here</scr"+"ipt>'; ?>";
```

This should output:

```
var html_1 = "<scr"+"ipt>adsense ad code here</scr"+"ipt>";
```

Which should work.

EDIT: You said this string is in a variable, try using `str_replace` to replace the tags.

```
var html_1 = "<?php echo str_replace(array('<script>','</script>'), array('<scr"+"ipt>', '</scr"+"ipt>'), $_SESSION['wpt_ad_content_1']); ?>";
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for providing a workable solution, unfortunately my real code looks like this, and it's content can be dynamic so I can't do this type of manual circumvention: var html_1 = "<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['wpt_ad_content_1']); ?>";

Comment: @atwellpub: Try this: `<?php echo str_replace(array('<script>','</script>'), array('<scr"+"ipt>', '</scr"+"ipt>'), $_SESSION['wpt_ad_content_1']); ?>;`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you could just put the javascript code in its own function, then just execute that function whenever you need it.  That sounds so obvious that you must have eliminated that option already, but why?

Answer (score 0):

`document.write('<script src="your_script.js"><\/script>')</script>`

Comment: Be careful with `document.write`, it will overwrite the page if it's ran after the page is finished loading.